# Can't run the upload sample of youtube data API v3

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

I'm getting started with the youtube API (and .net in general) and I get the error: 
"could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop"

I installed from NuGet the packages Google.Apis.Tasks.V1 and Google.Apis.Youtube.v3.

Both packages say they support .net 4.5

The sample code is this https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/dotnet/UploadVideo.cs

Where do I get that assembly?

Answer (score 0):

If your package manager installed all references, then it should be in Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.16\lib\net40.

I used this code to test youtube API upload, used .net  framework 4.0, and it worked. Try to see in this folder (or if you don't have newest Microsoft.Bcl.Async then in the one you have).